# When sockets are dereferenced, are they garbage collected

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand the concept of SO_TIMEOUT, threads resources and garbage collection.

I have seen a coding bug in my project where a set are sockets are wrongly dereferenced without closing.

And they get closed within few minutes with JAVA 1.6 but with JAVA 1.8 they take hours to close. [tested only on linux platform]

So I want to dig deeper into the issue.

I created this program in which I create 10 sockets but as you can see that 9 of them are derefernced and then the thread goes to long sleep duration:

```
    import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by 212477559 on 5/30/16.
 */
public class TestClientSocket {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket;
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                socket =new Socket("localhost",9090);
                socket.setKeepAlive(false);
            }


            Thread.sleep(900000);

        }
       catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("throws");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run

> netstat -np TCP | find "9090"

I can still see that after half an hour or so all sockets are still in established state. So I have following questions :

1) why those 9 sockets are not garbage collected?

2) is that thread still holding the resources?

3) are the below mentioned ways the only ways to close the sockets:

```
   1. close the sockets?
   2. Thread which created those sockets must exit?
   3. SO_TIMEOUT should expire?
```

Comment: closing the socket is the only right way to close a socket. Garbage collection is not a resource cleanup mechanism, neither are timeouts.

Comment: You might be tempted to write a `finalize()` method for this, but don't do it.  The garbage collector runs when free space in the heap is running low.  It does not run because of any other resource running low.

Comment: @zapl & james I understand the closing the sockets is the right way to do it. I just want to understand my project issue that where it went wrong in terms of different java versions. So I want to understand the relationship of sockets, threads and garbage collection

Comment: Your problem is simply that you didn't close your sockets. It's not thread related, the only socket in your test code referenced when thread sleeps is the last one created since `socket` still points to it. The rest is free to be GC's but your test program produces 0 garbage so  the GC doesn't need to run. And timeouts don't cause cleanup. They give you exceptions when you call a read or write method.

Comment: @zapl what do you mean by "your test program produces 0 garbage so the GC doesn't need to run"

Comment: The Garbage collector has no reason to run in your program. You create 10 objects, then sleep forever. No garbage is created afterwards. And nothing needs memory after that point either. Demand for memory is what drives garbage collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I digged deeper into this issue and find an interesting answer which was hinted by @Durandal and @Michael Markidis also.
What happened is that due to the coding bug in my code, the object was deferenced. 
Now the issue was that why this dereferenced object is not closing the sockets in java 1.8 but closing in java 1.6.

What I found is

- by default java 1.6 in my system allocated only 12 MB to survior space
- and by default java 1.8 in my system allocated  50 MB to survior space

Due to the small survior space, my old gen started filling quickly and which resulted into frequent major garbage collection in java 1.6.
But in java 1.8 major garbage collection happened after hours and just after that my sockets were closed.

So the issue was found out because of the change in behavior of allocating NEW_RATIO and SURVIVOR_RATIO by diff JVM versions.
When I tested with same NEW_RATIO and SURVIVOR_RATIO in java 1.8 **(which got allocated in java 1.6)**, I could see that my sockets were closed frequently.

Answer (score 3):

Garbage collection has nothing to do with the fact that these Sockets are still open.

**Just briefly**:

> Garbage collection is the process of looking at heap memory,
>   identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting
>   the unused objects. An in use object, or a referenced object, means
>   that some part of your program still maintains a pointer to that
>   object. An unused object, or unreferenced object, is no longer
>   referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an
>   unreferenced object can be reclaimed.

Now, although the the memory used by the Socket objects may be reclaimed, this doesn't mean that the Operating System handles to the Sockets are destroyed along with the process of the JVM reclaiming the memory (these are two separate things).

This is why a [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()) method has been provided for Sockets. This is the only way to guarantee that the Operating System will release the handle to the Socket.

Sockets should always be closed when they are no longer needed.

> And they get closed within few minutes with JAVA 1.6 but with JAVA 1.8
>   they take hours to close.

This should not even be a discussion point if they get closed.

Comment: From your answer, I got a clue that derefenced objects and sockets handlers are different thing. And also I agree that closing the sockets is the only good option. But what I want to understand now is that when having same platform, then how come having 2 different versions of java changes this behavior. If you can give any hints that where it might go wrong, that would be very helpful

Comment: Was this behavior consistent over several comparisons between 1.6 and 1.8?

Comment: yes, its consistent. Sockets count comes done in both of versions. But for java 1.8, it take hours as compared to minutes in java 1.6.  I know that garbage collection process is changed in java 1.8. Could it be the reason behind it?  Sorry, I am just sharing the hint, and dont have enough knowledge about the corelation

Comment: @Haj You may need to run a tool like VisualVM in both your tests in order to see what is really happening. Anything else may be pure speculation.

Answer (score 3):

When a native resource is represented by a java object, the object can be garbage collected while the resource stays allocated. To provide a safety net, the java object can override its finalize()-method to implement releasing the resource.

I presume somewhere in the concrete socket implementation there is a finalize, where this is handled, although I could not find the place on a quick glance at the source.

The problem with finalize is, it executes *only* when an object actually *is* garbarge collected, not when an object *becomes eligible* for GC. In your example code, your sockets are eligible for GC, but since all you do is sleep there is no pressure on the VM to actually perform a GC.

Edit: A point I did not stress or mention, because it is natural to me is: The *only* correct way to work with Sockets (or really anything that aquires an OS-Level resource) is to follow the close()/dispose() protocol the resource provides. Only by explicitly closing the resource as soon as you are done you can ensure the resource is released. In scenarios where the JVM heap and garbage collections are finely tuned objects may not be collected for extended periods of time (days or *weeks*, potentially *never*).

Comment: Your answer has good insight, but I don't think that the Socket class implements the finalize method in either JDK 1.6 or JDK 1.8

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis The socket class does not need to implement it, Socket is just a plain java object. If you take a look at the source you find that is delegates to SocketImpl (abstract), so presumably its left to the concrete implementation to handle finalizing. Or maybe it really does not implement it at all.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Finally found it, finalize is implemented in AbstractPlainSocketImpl.

Comment: Gotcha. So maybe the GC is getting called sooner in 1.6 vs 1.8??

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis yes, it seems to be getting called sooner in 1.6. But now I am confused after your answer that garbage collection and OS socket handles are different. So should I consider the insights about the garbage collection getting called sooner here?

Comment: @Haj It's really both of Durandal's and my answer that tell the whole story. While you can't depend on Garbage collection alone and you shouldn't. It turns out that the concrete implementation of the socket has a finalize method that calls the close method.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Thats quite probable, at least if IRC the default heap size has changed, the actual default GC has changed as well I believe. Finally the asker did not specify if he has actually *tested* the example with 1.6 or if the observation came from the actual application.

Comment: @Durandal could you specify more on this " at least if IRC the default heap size has changed, the actual default GC has changed as well I believe." And I am testing same project application in same linux platform with different java versions

Comment: @Haj No, I'm not a database for VM changes and 1.6 has been obsolete for years. Your best bet is scavenging blogs archives and articles for changes from 1.6 to 1.7 and 1.7 to 1.8. These things change, you move on, and forget about the old stuff. The better course of action for you is to actually *fix* the problem instead of looking for a workaround. An application that does not close its resources properly needs to be fixed, "it worked in environment X" is no justification not to fix it.